# Add custom metadata or config to package.json, is it valid?

Tags: node.js

I have seen (don't remember where) a package.json file with custom keys starting with an underscore:

```
{
    "name": "application-name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.4.7"
    , "jade": ">= 0.0.1"
  }
  , "_random": true
}
```

Are you allowed to do this?  Is it still valid?  If this is allowed, is there any documentation on the rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- Yes, **you're allowed** to add custom entries to `package.json`.
- Choose a key name:

  - **not already defined** (details below)
  - **not reserved** for future use (details below)
  - **avoid** prefixes **`_` and `$`**
  - and preferably **use a *single* top-level key** in which to ***nest* your custom entries**.

E.g., if you own domain `example.org`, you could store a custom `random` key as follows, **inside a top-level key in reverse-domain-name notation with `_` substituted for `.` and, if applicable, `-`**<sup>(see comments)</sup> (e.g., `org_example`):

```js
{
    "name": "application-name"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.4.7"
    , "jade": ">= 0.0.1"
  }  
  , "org_example": {
      "random": true
  }
}
```

To read such custom properties, use the following technique:

```
require("./package.json").org_example.random // -> true
```

---

**`npm`'s `package.json` file format mostly complies with the [CommonJS package specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1)**:

- **keys that `npm` currently uses**: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json
- **keys defined in the spec**: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1

As for **choosing custom keys**: the [CommonJS package specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1) states (emphasis mine):

> The following fields are **reserved** for **future** expansion: `build`, `default`, `email`, `external`, `files`, `imports`, `maintainer`, `paths`, `platform`, `require`, `summary`, `test`, `using`, `downloads`, `uid`.

> Extensions to the package descriptor specification should **strive to avoid collisions for future standard names by name-spacing their properties with innocuous names that do not have meanings relevant to general package management**.

> The following fields are **reserved for package registries** to use at their discretion: `id`, `type`.
> All **properties beginning with `_` or `$` are also reserved** for package registries to use at their discretion.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there any reason you recommend `"org_example"` instead of `"org.example"` – or an XML-namespace-like `"http://example.org"`?

Comment: @tomekwi: You _could_ use `org.example` or `http://example.org`, but, given that the JSON key names are also JavaScript object property names, it would make it awkward to access these properties later, because you'd have to use something like `pkg['org.example']`, because the more natural `pkg.<propertyname>` syntax wouldn't work with them.

Comment: @tomekwi: As for `@example`: I suppose that would work if you use your / your organization's npm username. Note that we're talking about a self-chosen convention in any case here, so personally I'd go for the reverse-domain-notation, because it is (a) common practice in other contexts), and (b) "more unique" than an npm username.

Comment: I’m not a fan of underscores, because semantically they are very ambigous. Some people use them as word separators, you use them as something stronger than word separators, and most text editors treat them as in-word characters. Try pasting `org_domain-name` into an editor and navigating back and forth with `CTRL` + arrows.

Comment: By the way, `org_domain-name` no longer works with dot syntax. I’m hesitating which convention to use in my project – and I think I’ll go for `http://domain-name.org` – it seems the safest and most explicit option.

Comment: @tomekwi: Yes, the very point of using `_`  is for, e.g.,  `org_example` to be recognized as a _single_ word, forming a  _regular JS property name_.
You're referring to `-` (hyphen) chars. in domain names, which indeed wouldn't work. However, you can replace `-` instances  with `_` instances as well;  while this renders the transformation potentially  _non-reversible_, it still strikes me as preferable to property names such as `http://domain-name.org`, especially in view of the fact that using `-` in domain names is increasingly rare.
However, this is ultimately a matter of preference.

Comment: I think the NPM team should choose a reserved property for this. Like "config", I don't know

Comment: I can't see my additional package.json properties today (4.11.2020) !!!! Why npm is striping this things.. :/ ?

Answer (score 20):

Given the nature of JSON and this statement from the [Nodejitsu documentation](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/npm/what-is-the-file-package-json) I don't see anything wrong with that.

> NPM itself is only aware of *two* fields in the package.json:

> 

```
{
   "name" : "barebones",
   "version" : "0.0.0",
}
```

NPM also cares about a couple of fields listed [here](http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html). So as long as it is valid JSON and doesn't interfere with Node.js or NPM everything should be alright and valid.

Node's awareness of package.json files seems extends to the *main* field. [Ref.](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_folders_as_modules)

> 

```
 { "name" : "some-library",
   "main" : "./lib/some-library.js" }
```

> If this was in a folder at ./some-library, then
> require('./some-library') would attempt to load
> ./some-library/lib/some-library.js.
>
> This is the extent of Node's awareness of package.json files.

To avoid possible conflicts you should prefixing your keys with some character or word. It is not recommended to use an underscore (_) or dollar sign ($) as those are reserved character prefixes, but other choices are viable.

Comment: It cares about more fields :P

Comment: With the benefit of 2+ years of hindsight: npm cares about many more fields (and node itself about a subset of them) - see https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html.
Do NOT use `_` (or `$`) for custom properties: "All properties beginning with _ or $ are also reserved for package registries to use at their discretion." - http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1
See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27232456/45375) for more.

Comment: I really recommend reading the [up-to-date answer by @mklement0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27232456/2816199).