# why npm add some property with underscore in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

when i perform `npm install koa-compose`, npm will auto add some property with underscore, What role do they have? like this:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      "koa-compose",
      "/Users/keenwon/Desktop/demo"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "koa-compose@latest",
  "_id": "koa-compose@2.4.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_installable": true,
  "_location": "/koa-compose",
  "_nodeVersion": "5.7.0",
  "_npmVersion": "3.7.5",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_spec": "koa-compose",
  "_where": "/Users/keenwon/Desktop/demo"
  "version": "2.4.0"
}
```

Comment: You mean in the `package.json` of the installed package, right?

Comment: I stumbled over this `_from`, too. Cloning a repository into two folders and running `npm install` in both, results in almost identical folders. Only difference are these `_from` entries. Sometimes they differ in `https` vs. `https+git` but sometimes they differ in the version field. What gives?

Comment: @keenwon I think it's added by either `npm` itself _or_ by the NPM repository and serves as metadata.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, they’re underscores, not underlines.

Comment: Although I don't know why, this package can easily remove them: [removeNPMAbsolutePaths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/removeNPMAbsolutePaths)

Comment: The following fields are reserved for package registries to use at their discretion: id, type. All properties beginning with _ or $ are also reserved for package registries to use at their discretion.
Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232456/6805529)
It is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [What are these properties prefixing underscore used for in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42625563/6307425)
Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42625703/6307425

> Those are meta data reserved for package registries. All properties beginning with _ or $ are reserved for package registries to use at their discretion. wiki common "Reserved Properties" section explains it.

Comment: This should be a comment, no?