# What are these properties prefixing underscore used for in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I found these properties prefixing underscore in package.json. What are they used for? why prefixing underscore on properties?

```
  "_from": "react-scripts@0.9.3",
  "_id": "react-scripts@0.9.3",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/react-scripts",
  "_nodeVersion": "6.0.0",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-18-east.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/react-scripts-0.9.3.tgz_1488303928068_0.6415497597772628"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "gaearon",
    "email": "dan.abramov@gmail.com"
  },
```

Answer (score 6):

Those are meta data reserved for package registries. All properties beginning with _ or $ are reserved for package registries to use at their discretion. [wiki common "Reserved Properties" section](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/1.1) explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is the reserved property of package.json, it is used for reserved keys.
So, it is clearly mentioned in [Documentation of package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) , we can't start a name with an underscore.