# Update a custom defined attribute in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

i want to add a custom key in package.json and update it through command line like.

`id: 1`

and by running a script it should update like:

`id: 2`

I have tried **npm version** it updates the version value but i don't want that i just want to update a custom value.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried (code)

Comment: Note: [package.json custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065564/add-custom-metadata-or-config-to-package-json-is-it-valid).

Answer (score 2):

To update the custom value, you can create a Node.js script that reads and modifies the package.json file.

`package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "id": 1,
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "update-id": "node update-id.js"
  }
}
```

`update-id.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');

const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));

packageJson.id += 1;

fs.writeFileSync('./package.json', JSON.stringify(packageJson, null, 2));
```

Comment: Please do not encourage bad questions by adding an answer to them.  Ask them to add clarity and code they have tried.